# Error when trying to create Backbone.js view subclass

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3.1, backbone.js, coffeescript

I have the backbone.js view below:

```
class MyApplication.Views.Cake extends Backbone.View
    tagName: 'li'
    className: 'cake'
```

and the attempted subclass

```
class MyApplication.Views.AwesomeCake extends MyApplication.Views.Cake
```

However in the javascript console the following error is thrown on the subclass:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out that my issue was a problem with Rails 3.1 and the asset pipeline.  Since sprockets loads the javascript files in alphabetical order (and because awesome_cake comes before cake) I needed to require the superclasses file.

```
#= require ./cake
class MyApplication.Views.AwesomeCake extends MyApplication.Views.Cake
```

Solution found in question:
[Backbone.js - Coffeescript extends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977032/backbone-js-coffeescript-extends)

Comment: Indeed!  A common problem.  :)